# Creating object in a for loop syntax error

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I am getting a syntax error on the following code for the line where I define the object within the for loop. What is going wrong here?

```js
var NAMES     = [ 'Accessories', 'Basins' ];      
var VARIANTS  = [ ['red','green','blue'], ['red','green','blue'] ];  
var numGroups = AD_GROUP_NAMES.length;
var INFO      = [];

for (var x = 0; x =< numGroups; x++) {
    var obj = { name : NAMES[x], variants : VARIANTS[x] };
    INFO.push(obj);
}
```

Any ideas? Any help appreciated.

Comment: `x =<numGroups` should be `x <=numGroups`

Comment: Where is *AD_GROUP_NAMES* defined?

Comment: array traversal for loop : `for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) `

Comment: what result do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Change comparison operator from `=<` to `>=`.

Also you should set `numGroups` to length - 1:  `var numGroups = AD_GROUP_NAMES.length - 1;`

```js
var NAMES     = [ 'Accessories', 'Basins' ];      
var VARIANTS  = [ ['red','green','blue'], ['red','green','blue'] ];  
var numGroups = 1 ;//AD_GROUP_NAMES.length - 1;
var INFO      = [];

for (var x = 0; x <= numGroups; x++) {
    var obj = { name : NAMES[x], variants : VARIANTS[x] };
    INFO.push(obj);
}

console.log(INFO);
```

Javascript comparison operators: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.3

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, use either ECMA-262 or MDN.

Comment: @RobG ok, I changed the reference